# Div Lightbox JQueryPlug-in

Tags: jquery

i am searching for a Div Lightbox JQuery Plugin that executes automatically when i enter the web page. Example :www.alljobs.co.il (like the popup div)

Answer (score 0):

Any lightbox plugin should be fine, you'd just need run the call for the plugin in the:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Check out [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) and look at the "Inline" example down the page.